# getting the contents of a div tag with class

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I am trying to read the particular contents of an child IFrame wrapped in a div tag  from parent window. I am using

```
detailsValue = window.frames['myIframe'].document.getElementById('result').innerHTML;
```

with this I'm able to access the entire content of that frame. But I need to access only a portion of that content. The problem is that the div which wraps the content that I am looking for contains only class and no ID.

```
<div class="watINeed"> <table class="details"> </table> </div>
```

I am unable to access the content which is in a form of table (with no id and only class).

Any help.

**Edit1:** I need to access the content of the table to check for char length and also for some html tags present in that content.

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll(".className")[0]` or `$(".className")[0]`

Comment: @Banana Not working. No response. when I changed to `window.frames['myIframe'].document.querySelectorAll(".watINeed")[0]`

Comment: do you receive cross-origin permission denied error in console?

Comment: @Banana Nope, I am sure that this is from same domain. I am not getting any error, but no response as well.

Comment: you are most likely executing the code before the iframe content loads. wrap your code with `window.onload=function(){};`

Comment: there are more things, wait ill post an answer with examples

Comment: @Banana I am executing the code with only after the page loads.

Comment: ive posted an answer, have a look.

Comment: @Banana I am posted my response. Still don't work. I am unable to read the content of the table.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this either using plain Javascript (as mentioned by Notulysses):

```
window.frames['myIframe'].document.querySelector('.watINeed .details')
```

or using jQuery (since you aded [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery)) by specifying the iframe's `document` as [context](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery1) to `$`:

```
$(".watINeed .details", window.frames['myIframe'].document)
```

In the latter case you've a fullfeatured jQuery object.

Note that in either case the iframe's document has to be on the same domain otherwise you'd run into cross origin issues.

Tested against jQuery 2.0.x

#### Update

If you're running the selector during page load of the including page, you'll have to listen to the `load` event of the iframe before accessing its content:

```
$(window.frames['myIframe']).on("load", function(){
     // above query here  
});
```

Comment: When I use javascript no response. If i use jquery option i get "DOM Exception: SYNTAX_ERR (12)" error.

Comment: Sounds like your selector is bad. What's the selector you're using or you'd like to use? Put it into your question by editing it.

Comment: I tried what you have mentioned above as well as `window.frames['myIframe'].document.querySelectorAll('.watINeed .details')` as suggested by @Banana

Answer (score 0):

If your are looking for a vanilla Javascript, and your target `div` is a direct children of starting selector, it is a simple task

```
   var detailsValue = window.frames['myIframe'].document.getElementById('result').innerHTML;
    var target;
    for(var i = 0; i< detailsValue.children.lenght; i ++){
     if(detailsValue.children[i].getAttribute('class')== 'watINeed'){
      target = detailsValue.children[i] ;

     }
    }
```

otherwise, have to write a recursive method to scrap all children of structure

Answer (score 0):

As i wrote above, it can be done using the following:

```
document.querySelectorAll(".className")[0] or $(".className")[0]
```

those are basically the same as both return a list of nodes and the `[0]` simply means taking the first result from the list.

**there are 2 things to pay attention to:**

- the iframe loads the content asynchronously therefore when you execute the query its most likely that the elements you are searching for did not load yet.
  **executing the code after DOM loads is not enough**.

   the solution is simply put your code in a block that executes once **all the asynchronous content is loaded:**

  ```
  window.onload=function(){
      window.frames['myIframe'].document.querySelectorAll(".watINeed")[0];
  }
  ```

  or the jQuery alternative:

  ```
  $(window).load(function(){
      window.frames['myIframe'].document.querySelectorAll(".watINeed")[0];
  });
  ```
- the second thing is, according to the page <kbd>[Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe)</kbd>, you can access the iframe's document using `contentWindow.document`:

  ```
  window.onload=function(){
      window.frames['myIframe'].contentWindow.document.querySelectorAll(".watINeed")[0];
  }
  ```

  or the jQuery alternative:

  ```
  $(window).load(function(){
      window.frames['myIframe'].contentWindow.document.querySelectorAll(".watINeed")[0];
  });
  ```

live example: <kbd>**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TheBanana/h3Kvd/)**</kbd>

Comment: Thanks for the code sample. However, I am getting "**Unable to get value of the property 'document': object is null or undefined**
" error when I use "contentWindow". And still no response with document.querySelectorAll(".watINeed")[0]. I am sure that the code is executed only after the Iframe is loaded.

Comment: as you can see in the fiddle, the code works. the error you receive about the document being undefined, it might be due to browser not supporting the contentWindow. try `frame.contentDocument.query...` instead. and also, is your code wrapped with window.onload ? because thats the only way it would run after the entire page is fully loaded

Comment: The fiddle response is also undefined. [check this] (http://jsfiddle.net/h3Kvd/1/)

Comment: IE9 and IE8 are our supporting browsers. I tried with IE8 and firefox both did not work

Comment: it seems IE does not support `.frames[]` for some reason. you have to change `window.frames['myIframe']` to `document.getElementById("test_Frame")` for IE browsers

Comment: I dnt think so. With `window.frames['myIframe'].document.getElementById('result')` I am able to view entire iframe content. So I don't understand why it wont work.

Comment: then only explanation would be cross-origin. have a look here: http://javascript.info/tutorial/same-origin-security-policy